# GetDpiForWindow() is not declared when compiled using MinGW-w64 GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw-w64

I currently building a Direct2D program. I use MinGW-w64 GCC to compile my program. However, it seems that there is no `GetDpiForWindow()` even though the Windows Documentation said there was. I have tried to build the same program in Visual Studio 2022, and it was working fine. `GetDpiForWindow()` doesn't exists when I compile the program using GCC...

```
./src/main.cpp: In member function 'bool MainWindow::ConfigureSwapChain(HWND)':
./src/main.cpp:208:20: error: 'GetDpiForWindow' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'GetTopWindow'?
  208 |         UINT dpi = GetDpiForWindow(_phwnd);
```

Basically, when I tried to call `GetDpiForWindow()`, it fails to build.

Here is my gcc command:

```
gcc -x c++ ./main.h ./main.cpp -o ./app -mwindows -municode -luser32 -lgdi32 -lkernel32
```

Let me know if I miss something.

Comment: Check the requirements section

Comment: @Axalo the requirement is the `User32.lib` and `Windows.h` header file, that's why I specify the `-luser32` flag. At the bottom of the documentation page, it says "[desktop apps only]" I am not sure what does that mean, because I clearly using `-mwindows` flag...

Comment: `Minimum supported client: Windows 10, version 1607 [desktop apps only]`. There are different versions of `Windows.h` because there are different versions of Windows. Yours does not contain `GetDpiForWindow()`. Use `GetProcAddress()` or look for alternatives such as `GetDpiForMonitor()`.

Comment: @Axalo alright, thank you for the suggestion. I am just afraid if my Direct2D program will go wrong, because since the beginning I was using GetDpiForWindow().